# Meaning of the WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE message

Tags: c, windows, winapi, gdi

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/wm-syscolorchange):

> WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE message is sent to all top-level windows when a
>   change is made to a system color setting.
>
> Applications that have brushes using the existing system colors should
>   delete those brushes and re-create them using the new system colors.

Declare global variable

```
HBRUSH g_hBackground = NULL;
```

In WM_CREATE message handler create background brush

```
case WM_CREATE:
g_hBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE + 1);
break;
```

Use brush in paint message

```
case WM_PAINT:
hdc = BeginPaint(hwnd, &ps);
FillRect(hdc, &rcClient, g_hBackground);
EndPaint(hwnd, &ps);
break;
```

Handle system color change

```
case WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE:
if (g_hBackground)
{
    DeleteObject(g_hBackground);
}

g_hBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE + 1);
break;
```

Now, I change system color in control panel, everything works, background is painted with new color.

Delete all WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE handler code, I change system color in control panel, everything works too, background is painted with new color.

So why I need this message?

**THE QUESTION**

**What is the meaning this message for the top-level window?**

Only forwarding this message to the child windows?
Or I missed something?

Comment: What do you mean with "Comment all WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE"?

Comment: Simply imagine remove all WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE code, pass this message to the DefWindowProc

Comment: You didn't create a brush, that requires CreateSolidBrush().  That you can cast an integer to a HBRUSH is wonky but goes back to the early days when Windows had to run in 256KB of RAM.  It is normally only used when you initialize the struct for RegisterWindow/Ex().

Comment: Imagine you create a real brush using `CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE))` and cache that in a variable. You would have to handle `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` to update that variable.

Comment: Thanks both. Do I need refactor code to call CreateSolidBrush or left hbrush as is ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was important in the early days when displays could only display 256 colors.  (Or if your system boots in Safe Mode when Windows can't access a native true color display mode.)  A system color change meant a (potential) change in the palette, so applications would have to adjust which color index they would use to draw their windows.

These days, if you change a color from (for example) green to blue, any window or control that uses that RGB color for drawing needs to be notified of the updated color so that it conform to the new color scheme.  Brushes created from an index color like `COLOR_3D_FACE` or via a call to `GetSysColorBrush()` will automatically use the new color on the next redraw.

If you call `CreateSolidBrush` based off of a system color (`GetSysColor()`), you'll need to update the brush (recreate it) when you receive the `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` message.

Comment: _"Brushes created from an index color like COLOR_3D_FACE will use automatically use the new color on the next redraw."_ -- You are propably referring to `GetSysColorBrush()`, where the documentation states _"System color brushes track changes in system colors."_. When you create a brush like `CreateSolidBrush(GetSysColor(COLOR_3DFACE))` you would have to handle `WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE` to update that brush.

Comment: @zett42 I've added to my answer based on your comment.  I was specifically thinking of the `g_hBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_3DFACE + 1)` in OP's code.